# Extender sessão no PHP usando .htaccess

Tags: php, htaccess, session

Como extender uma sessão no PHP usando o .htaccess?

Eu usei este código abaixo:

```
php_value session.cookie_lifetime 28800
php_value session.cache_expire 28800
php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 28800
```

Porém acredito que não tenha funcionado, alias, tem como verificar se a sessão que iniciei está com este tempo de expiração?

Qual seria o tempo de expiração da sessão(cookie) padrão?

Acredito que o trecho do código *.cache_expire não tem a ver com a sessão, posso retirar do código?

Comment: eu achei este exemplo https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6075770/php-session-timeout, que é mais ou menos parecido com o seu, segundo o cara , vc deve adicionar somente php_value session.cookie_lifetime 18000 e php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 18000. Quanto ao tempo padrão do cookie não sei responder.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Faz o set de duracao em segundos
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 3600);

// Seta o cookie em segundos
session_set_cookie_params(3600);    

/*
     * Pagina de login
     */
    if($login){
        $_SESSION['CREATED'] = time();
    }

    /*
     * Funcao para verificar o tempo da session
     */
    if (time() - $_SESSION['CREATED'] > 1800) { // Tempo em segundos

        session_regenerate_id(true);    // Regenera o id da session para prevenir o session fixation
        $_SESSION['CREATED'] = time();  // Atualiza o tempo da session
    }
```